# Does there always exist an injective map in the algebraic dual space $X^*$ of an infinite-dimensional t.v.s $X$?

Tags: analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space with $\mathrm{dim}\ X=\infty$ and let $X^*$ be its algebraic dual space, that is the set of all linear maps from $X \to \mathbb C$.

Does there always exist a injective map in $X^*$? If so, why? Or can you give me an exmaple?

Thanks!

Comment: How can there be an injective linear function from any space of dimension greater than 1 into the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element $f$ of $X^{*}$ is injective then $X$ is necessarily one dimensional since any non-zero linear functinal $f$ is also surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(b_i)_{i \in I}$ be a (linear/Hamel) basis for $X$.

For each $i$ define a linear map $f_i: X \to \Bbb C$ by sending $b_i$ to $1 \in \Bbb C$ (and all $b_j, j \neq i$ to $0$) and extending linearly.

Then define $i: X \to X^\ast$ by linearity: Write $x=\sum_{i \in F} c_i b_i$ for some finite subset $F \subseteq I$ and complex coefficients $c_i$, in a unique way. Then $i(x)=\sum_{i \in F}c_i f_i \in X^\ast$ is a well-defined member of $X^\ast$ and $x \neq y$ implies $i(x) \neq i(y)$, so this defines a linear injection from $X$ into $X^\ast$.

The size of the basis doesn't matter (we need AC to get a basis of course) and I don't see any topological connection: the $f_i$ will not be continuous in general, and neither will $i$ be. But there was no question of that.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This answer assumes that $V^*$ consists of *continuous* linear functionals.

The other answers explain why there is never an injective map. The situation can be worse. It may happen that there are no surjective maps, i.e. no non-zero functionals.

Consider $V:= L^p([0,1])$ with $0 < p < 1$, which becomes a topological vector space for the metric

$$d(f,g) = \int_{[0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|^p dx$$

Then one can show that $V^*= \{0\}$ (by showing for example that the only convex neighborhood of $0$ is $V$ itself). In particular, there are no injective/surjective functionals.